# How to filter Dataframes with column values of other ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two list of dataframes. I want to filter the first with condition(> or <) present in another ones.
The first that i would filter:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car', 'bike','car', 'motorbike','bike'], 'Amount': [40, 3,50, 699,60], 'Count': [10, 1,2,4,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Parameters': ['Amount', 'Count'], 'car': [30, 3,], 'bike': [40,4,]})
```

i want to impose the condition: that filter all the dataframe: i want the df1 dataframes that have the Type equal to columns car or bike or motorbike > of the respective column in the df2 (Amount AND Count).
So the result:

```
dfTotal = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car'], 'Amount': [40], 'Count': [10]})
```

**UPDATE**: what happen if i have that df1 now? because i can have more equal type with different Amount and Count, and they are different Dataframes. The custom solution in this case wont work because types are not distinct.

Comment: your inputs are not reproducible, (missing `DataFrame`, non-quoted strings, uneven lists, missing commas). Please make an effort and double-check that this is correct before posting

Comment: No is not. Missing value on `df2` for `Parameters` column.

Comment: No it's not, make sure to **check** ;)

Comment: Are you also sure of the output? in df1 count for car is 40, which is > than 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# set the indexes, transpose df2, then check if all columns match
keep = df1.set_index('Type').ge(df2.set_index('Parameters').T).all(axis=1)

# filter types to keep
out = df1.loc[df1['Type'].isin(keep[keep].index)]
```

Output:

```
  Type  Amount  Count
0  car      40     10
```

Used input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car', 'bike', 'motorbike'],
                    'Amount': [40, 3, 699],
                    'Count': [10, 1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Parameters': ['Amount', 'Count'],
                    'car': [30, 3],
                    'bike': [40, 8]})
```

##### custom conditions per column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['car', 'bike', 'motorbike'], 'Amount': [40, 3, 699], 'Count': [10, 1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Parameters': ['Amount', 'Count'], 'car': [30, 40], 'bike': [3, 8]})

tmp1 = df1.set_index('Type')
tmp2 = df2.set_index('Parameters').T

# combine custom conditions
keep = tmp1['Amount'].gt(tmp2['Amount']) & tmp1['Count'].lt(tmp2['Count'])

# filter types to keep
out = df1[df1['Type'].map(keep)]
```

Comment: How to do if i want to use the operator ">" in the Amount and the ">" in the Count?

Comment: `ge` is `>=`. You can use `(df1.set_index('Type') > df2.set_index('Parameters').T).all(axis=1)`, but honestly `gt`/`ge` are often a better syntax in pandas

Comment: Ok, but in this way i can't filter by Amount and by Count with the "&" with different conditions (for example: Car with Amount <40 & Count <=8) , no? because i see that in this way i can filter with one condition for both.

Comment: please be explicit in your question, don't leave out details

Comment: Thank you very much @mozway, the custom conditions are what i had in mind!

Comment: I added an update in the question and i modified the df1, how to do in this case?

Comment: @Marco I don't know, a description is ambiguous. You must provide explicit examples as DataFrame constructors. Also please don't change your question repeatedly, rather ask a new one